# No such file or directory when caching bitmap?

Tags: android

I keep getting this error

```
07-28 19:32:40.536: ERROR/error(534): java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
07-28 19:32:40.536: ERROR/error(534):     at java.io.File.createNewFileImpl(Native Method)
07-28 19:32:40.536: ERROR/error(534):     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1115)
07-28 19:32:40.536: ERROR/error(534):     at com.fttech.gameIT.MainMenu.putBitmapInDiskCache(MainMenu.java:447)
```

Here is my putBitmapInDiskCache()

```
    public void putBitmapInDiskCache(URI imageUri, Bitmap avatar) {   

                    File cacheDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails");    
                    File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, ""+imageUri.hashCode());     
                    try {      
                    cacheFile.createNewFile();       
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);    
                    avatar.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);       
                    fos.flush();       
                    fos.close();    
                    } catch (Exception e) {       
                    Log.e("error", "Error when saving image to cache. ", e);    

                    }  



                    }
```

EDIT: That worked! Now i get this...

```
07-28 19:56:31.525: ERROR/DEBUGTAG(573): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /881625833 (No such file or directory)
 07-28 19:56:31.525: ERROR/DEBUGTAG(573):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
  07-28 19:56:31.525: ERROR/DEBUGTAG(573):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:239)
07-28 19:56:31.525: ERROR/DEBUGTAG(573):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:88)
 07-28 19:56:31.525: ERROR/DEBUGTAG(573):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:122)
 07-28 19:56:31.525: ERROR/DEBUGTAG(573):     at com.fttech.gameIT.MainMenu$ImageAdapter.getView(MainMenu.java:297)
 07-28 19:56:31.525: ERROR/DEBUGTAG(573):     at android.widget.Gallery.makeAndAddView(Gallery.java:748)
 07-28 19:56:31.525: ERROR/DEBUGTAG(573):     at android.widget.Gallery.fillToGalleryLeft(Gallery.java:667)
```

Code i am using to retrieve the images from the cache..

```
try {


                                URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);



                                URI imageUri = null;
                                try {
                                    imageUri = aURL.toURI();
                                } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                if (new File(new File(myContext.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails"), "" + imageUri.hashCode()).exists())
                                {
                                    String cachFile = ""+imageUri.hashCode();
                                    FileInputStream fis;

                                    try {
                                        fis = new FileInputStream(cachFile);
                                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis); 
                                         i.setImageBitmap(bm);
                                            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                                            /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
                                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
                                                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(450, 300));
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(125, 125));
                                            }


                                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                                           Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);





                                            /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
                                            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                                            /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
                                            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
                                                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(450, 300));

                                            return i;
                                            }
                                                i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(125, 125));
                                                return i;
                                            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a  `cacheDir.mkdirs()` call. Do that and then do `File cacheFile...`

Comment: It should be like this: File cacheDir = new File(this.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails");cacheDir.mkdirs();File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, ""+imageUri.hashCode());

Comment: The images dissapear when one is swipped out of view. one by one

Comment: You are creating a file in "thumbnails" folder but trying to read from root but not thumbnails.

Comment: You need to learn a bit more about programming :) String cachFile = this.getCacheDir() +"/thumbnails/"+imageUri.hashCode();

Comment: That did it!!! And i know. Im a senior in HS taking my second year in java and C++. So im still pretty knew but adapted to android very fast. Just not very good when it comes down to the VERY complex code like you guys are. How did you get so well anyway? And btw what happens if the images change? meaning they arent the same images? Will the cache eventually fill up?

Comment: If you are new to programming then I understand, as long as you enjoy it dont give up if you find it hard. The cacheDir folder is emptied by Android if it is running low on resources/file system space. So it is recommended that for any important data you save it on server, or on a SD card. Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html, and good luck.

Comment: Thanks alot man, and i havent gave up, my desk is full of android and java books. lol. I love this stuff, Its what im born to do! Thanks for all your help, Wish i could vote you up 1 million times

Comment: Btw do you have gTalk or anthing so we can stay in touch?

Comment: I may need your help in the furture, it would be great.

Comment: Your email wasn't on your profile. But mine. Is. Email me so I'll have it.

Comment: Hm, it should have, been, leme check.

Comment: It only gives location and websites

Comment: hm, well then, my email address is same username at yahoo.com